# AS3 Separating Arrays for different items

Tags: arrays, list, actionscript-3, associative-array

I have a function that creates a new value inside an associative array.

```
var array:Array = new Array(new Array());
var i : int = 0;

function personVelgLand(evt:MouseEvent)
{
    for(i = 0; i < personListe.dataProvider.length; i++)
    {
        if(txtPersonVelg.text == personListe.dataProvider.getItemAt(i).label)
        {
            personListe.dataProvider.getItemAt(i).reise = array;
            personListe.dataProvider.getItemAt(i).reise.push(landListe.selectedItem.land);
        }
    }
}
```

What happens is that the 'array' array which becomes 'personListe.dataProvider.getItemAt(i).reise' applies to every item in the list. I want it so that each time the function runs that the .reise only applies to the item chosen and not all of them.

EDIT:

I did this:

```
personListe.dataProvider.getItemAt(i).reise = new Array(array);
```

And now they are not the same but now each item in the list can not have multiple .reise values...

EDIT 2: dataProvider is nothing it would work just as fine without it. .reise is created in the function I originally posted it creates `.reise` in the object `getItemAt(i)`.

personListe is a list which the users add their own items to by the use of a input textfield. It is given by this function:

```
function regPerson(evt:MouseEvent)
{
    regPersoner.push(txtRegPerson.text);

    personListe.addItem({label:regPersoner});

    regPersoner = new Array();
    txtRegPerson.text = "";
}
```

EDIT 3 : The user can register names which turn in to labels in a list. There is also list with 3 countries, Spain, Portugal and England. The user can then register a country to a person they select. Thats when I want to create the .reise inside the "name" items in the first list which contains the countries they have selected. I want every name to be able to select multiple countries which then will be created in the element .reise inside the item that holds their name. This would be easy if I could use strings. But later I plan to have the user type in a country and then something that would show every user that have selected that country. That is why the countries need to be stored as arrays inside the "name" items..

Comment: I think you need to explain/show us what `personListe` is, what `dataProvider` is, what `reise` is

Comment: Could you rephrase your question a bit?  I'm really struggling to parse this sentence: "The problem is that every new value that are supposed to be pushed into the array and then into the different items are applied to all items in the list when the function runs. How do I make the values seperate for each item?"

Comment: What happens is that the array `array` which becomes `personListe.dataProvider.getItemAt(i).reise` applies to every item in the list. I want each time the function runs that the .reise only applies to the item chosen and not all of them

Comment: @Jezzamon see my edits

Comment: @Brian I don't know if you get notified or not

Comment: -1 it's totally unclear to me what you are trying to do. The problem is that you explain your problem with code that is not doing what you want. Take a step back. Explain the big picture idea, without using any code in plain English. What are you trying to accomplish? What's the context of your application? Please stop throwing `new Array()` at everything.

Comment: @null I edited my question, look at edit 3 at the bottom..

Comment: What do those lists look like? What components are you using?

Comment: @null the standard list component

Comment: I didn't get notified until you typed @Brian :)  So, are you saying that when you run your code, every user in `personListe` gets the same array set in its `reise` property?  According to the code you posted, that shouldn't happen.  Your loop *should* limit that to only the one user.  Unless you're setting that same array to `.reise` in some other code?  Why are you setting `.reise` in that location at all?  That will naturally override whatever array you've already set for `.reise`

Comment: @Brian The .reise element does not exist before i set it in that function. So I am setting it there so I can show where the person wants to go in a textfield later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first create a class for the `User` data that you are modelling. You already know all the properties.

> - The user can register names
> - The user can then register a country to a person they select.
> - able to select multiple countries

Such a class could look like this:

```
package
{
    public class User
    {
        private var _name:String;
        private var _countries:Array;
        
        public function User(name:String)
        {
            _name = name;
            _countries = [];
        }
        
        public function get name():String
        {
            return _name;
        }
        
        public function get countries():Array
        {
            return _countries;
        }
        
        public function set countries(value:Array):void
        {
            _countries = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now create a `DataProvider`, fill it with objects of that class and use it for the list [as described here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fce.html):

```
import fl.controls.List; 
import fl.data.DataProvider; 
 
var users:List = new List(); 

users.dataProvider = new DataProvider([
                            new User("David"), 
                            new User("Colleen"), 
                            new User("Sharon"), 
                            new User("Ronnie"), 
                            new User("James")]); 
                            
addChild(users); 
users.move(150, 150);
```

In order to get a label from a `User` object, define a [`labelFunction`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/List.html#labelFunction)

```
import fl.controls.List; 
import fl.data.DataProvider; 
 
var users:List = new List(); 

users.labelFunction = userLabelFunction;

function userLabelFunction(item:Object):String 
{
    return  item.name;
}

users.dataProvider = new DataProvider([
                            new User("David"), 
                            new User("Colleen"), 
                            new User("Sharon"), 
                            new User("Ronnie"), 
                            new User("James")]); 
                            
addChild(users); 
users.move(150,150);
```

This way you do not have to add a `label` property that you don't want in your class.

---

Selecting a name means selecting a user. The list of countries associated to the name should show up in a second `List`.

The `DataProvider` of that `List` remains constant, a list of all the available countries.

```
import fl.controls.List; 
import fl.data.DataProvider; 
 
 
// list of users

var users:List = new List(); 
addChild(users); 
users.move(150,150);

users.labelFunction = userLabelFunction;

function userLabelFunction(item:Object):String 
{
    return  item.name;
}

users.dataProvider = new DataProvider([
                            new User("David"), 
                            new User("Colleen"), 
                            new User("Sharon"), 
                            new User("Ronnie"), 
                            new User("James")]); 
                            

// lsit of countries

var countries:List = new List(); 
addChild(countries); 
countries.move(550,150); // adjut position as desired

countries.dataProvider = new DataProvider([
                            {label:"a"}, 
                            {label:"b"}, 
                            {label:"c"}, 
                            {label:"d"}, 
                            {label:"e"}, 
                            {label:"f"}]);
```

Now all you have to do is to wire it all up. If a user is selected, select his countries in the countries list. If a country is selected, add that to the currently selected users list of countries. That could look somethign like this:

```
users.addEventLsitener(Event.CHANGE, onUserSelected);

function onUserSelected(e:Event):void
{
    countries.selectedItems = users.selectedItem.countries;
}

countries.addEventLsitener(Event.CHANGE, onCountrySelected);

function onCountrySelected(e:Event):void
{
    users.selectedItem.countries = countries.selectedItems;
}
```

---

The full code could look like this. I did not test this, but you get the idea.

```
// list of users

var users:List = new List(); 
addChild(users); 
users.move(150,150);

users.labelFunction = userLabelFunction;

function userLabelFunction(item:Object):String 
{
    return  item.name;
}

users.dataProvider = new DataProvider([
                            new User("David"), 
                            new User("Colleen"), 
                            new User("Sharon"), 
                            new User("Ronnie"), 
                            new User("James")]); 
                            

// list of countries

var countries:List = new List(); 
addChild(countries); 
countries.move(550,150); // adjut position as desired

countries.dataProvider = new DataProvider([
                            {label:"a"}, 
                            {label:"b"}, 
                            {label:"c"}, 
                            {label:"d"}, 
                            {label:"e"}, 
                            {label:"f"}]); 
                            
// events

users.addEventLsitener(Event.CHANGE, onUserSelected);

function onUserSelected(e:Event):void
{
    countries.selectedItems = users.selectedItem.countries;
}

countries.addEventLsitener(Event.CHANGE, onCountrySelected);

function onCountrySelected(e:Event):void
{
    users.selectedItem.countries = countries.selectedItems;
}
```

> From what I understand this seems to work except for the fact that the names are already provided when the program starts. What I want is that the user adds the name themselves while the program is running.

You can add new items with the methods provided by the `DataProvider` class, like `addItem()` for example. Just add new `User` objects.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I have never used packages before so I do not know that much about it. I have seen that it is a recommended practice so I will recreate this project with packages and start learning to use them.

From what I understand this seems to work except for the fact that the names are already provided when the program starts. What I want is that the user adds the name themselves while the program is running.  I am sorry if I have misunderstood you but as I said I am not familiar with packages. I will come back to study your code tomorrow or the day after.

Comment: It seemed like your use of packages made it much simpler to accomplish what I want. I will try my best to understand what you have answered later in a couple of days. Sorry if I have been unclear about my questions and what I want my program to do.

Comment: @elektroluse you can always add more items. See my edit.